# React Router Dom V6 - Lost Search Parameter on Refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Every time I reload my page (<kbd>F5</kbd>) my website lost the running query parameter.

Ex:

```
http://127.0.0.1:5173/subscriber/123456789?searchType=document
```

When I manually reload the page, it changes automatically to:

```
http://127.0.0.1:5173/subscriber/123456789
```

And then I lost the reference on which type of information my code need to search.
Below is my component:

**SearchSubscriber.jsx**

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Outlet, useNavigate, createSearchParams } from "react-router-dom";

export default function SearchSubscriber() {
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    const [searchProperties, setSearchProperties] = useState({ type: "document", value: "" });

    async function handleSearch(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        navigate({
            pathname: searchProperties.value,
            search: createSearchParams({
                searchType: searchProperties.type,
            }).toString(),
        });
    }

    return (
        <>
            <form onSubmit={handleSearch}>
                <select
                    value={searchProperties.type}
                    onChange={(e) => setSearchProperties({ type: e.target.value, value: "" })}>
                    <option value="document">Document</option>
                    <option value="mail">E-Mail</option>
                </select>
                <br />
                <input
                    type="text"
                    value={searchProperties.value}
                    onChange={(e) => setSearchProperties({ ...searchProperties, value: e.target.value })}
                />

                <button type="submit">Search</button>
            </form>
            <Outlet />
        </>
    );
}
```

**Subscriber**

```js
import { useParams, useSearchParams } from "react-router-dom";

export default function Subscriber() {
    const { key } = useParams();
    const [queryParameters] = useSearchParams();

    return (
        <>
            Searching {queryParameters.get("searchType")} for {key}
        </>
    );
}
```

Can someone help me?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is there anything in your code, any place, where it is enqueueing any navigation actions that are clearing the queryString part of the URL? Note that this includes accidental omissions as well. I don't see anything in the shared code snippet that removes the queryString. See [mcve].

Comment: Hudson, make sure it's not your backend doing it.

Comment: @DrewReese There isn't any extra part. Im using that exact same piece of code in my project.

Comment: @RoboRobok unfortunately no. In this piece of code im not even connecting with backend.

Comment: I meant somewhere else in your app that does any navigation actions when the app is mounting, for example maybe there's an auth redirect that occurs prior to an auth status is confirmed and redirected back sans the queryString. The point of what I'm saying is that the code you've shared isn't removing any part of the queryString from what I can see.

Comment: Here's a running [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-dom-v6-lost-search-parameter-on-refresh-c3k9s7?file=/src/App.js) demo of your code. Note that once you are redirected to `"/subscribers"`, enter a search value and search/navigate to `"/subscribers/:key"` the queryString remains in the URL in the address bar through page reloads. I'm not able to reproduce the issue with this code.

Comment: @DrewReese That was exactly what you was saying. On my authentication context, in some moment, i was navigating user using `navigate(location.pathname)` instead the whole `location` object... Wich didn't gave me the `search` prop.

I really appreciate your help. Thank you so much!

Comment: Awesome, glad you found the culprit and sounds like you you were able to rectify the issue. Cheers and good luck.

Answer (score -1):

You are storing the search parameter in state `const [searchProperties, setSearchProperties] = useState({ type: "document", value: "" });`. Evertime you refresh a react app the state returns to default. In your case the values are empty. To avoid this you can use `react-persist` to ensure the values stay in state even after a refresh or store the values in `localstorage` and use the `useEffect` hook to pull any values stored in the `localstorage` before the component is mounted

**EDIT**

If you've set the route to `/subscriber/123456789` or `/subscriber/:id`, the URL will default to that on refresh as the query params are only added to the route on submit

Comment: Yes, the local state will reset. OP is saying the queryString is removed from the URL in the address bar when they reload the app.

Comment: @DrewReese Exactly. My intention isn't to keep my state while refreshing... But, keep my query param `?searchType=document` while refreshing

Comment: You can check and see and my edit as to what I think might be causing the issue. If that is not the case, then maybe you can make a working sandbox and share the link so debugging might be easier